# How to Hide Closed Items in org-agenda

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

How to hide the closed or DONE/CANCELLED items in agenda view like this?  [image]

By default `org-agenda-log-mode-items` is set to `'(closed clock)`. So it will show both clocked and closed items in agenda view.

I set it to `'(clock)` to hide the closed items but it is still in agenda view.

Emacs version: GNU Emacs 29.0.50 (build 1, aarch64-apple-darwin21.2.0, NS appkit-2113.20 Version 12.1 (Build 21C52)) of 2022-01-27

Comment: After I `(setq org-agenda-log-mode-items '(clock))` `org-agenda-log-mode` only show the clock items. Can you reproduce with `emacs -Q`

Comment: I tried with Emacs -Q so no other customisation but it still doesn't work for me. is it a bug? how do I check?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. Just make sure you reopen org-agenda mode after change `org-agenda-log-mode-items` @NickD Any suggestions?

Comment: @TianshuWang yeah I did that. I also tried it on emacs nightly build but couldn't get it working. I will try it on later on my linux box.